# what is dashboard?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, dashboard

Can any body please explain me, what is dashboard in salesforce? And how to use it in salesforce
please provide me steps to do dashboard. If possible please also provide any link available.

Thanks
Anu

Answer (score 0):

No need for the sass, the guy is new to stackoverflow and probably new to salesforce.

Go to youtube, there are a bunch of your long videos on there technologies. Also, there's a free book called force.com fundamentals which has a chapter on the topic. For help, user IRC #salesforce or @salesforce on twitter.

Good luck